# How do I use the Tex Gyre Schola font with fontspec in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, compilation-error

So I was trying to migrate from LuaTeX to XeTeX in overleaf and when I switched the compiler, It suddenly shows this error:

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "Tex Gyre Schola" cannot be found.
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

xetex is less forgiving about errors in the font name.

```
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}
```

should be

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
```

note: X not x